# Scala child class inherits parent class traits?

Tags: scala, inheritance

Why if I have:

```
trait T {
  def method(a: Int)
}

class A extends T {
  //...
}

class B extends A {
  //...
}
```

then when I do this:

```
//...
val b = new B
b.method(15)
//...
```

the `method()` is said to be undefined for B? Why do I have to explicitly say that

```
class B extends A with T
```

in order to obtain what I want? Are not traits of parent classes inherited? How can it be so if they may realize a big part of parent's own methods which are inherited by definition? If it is so, what is the argument?

Comment: The above doesn't compile unless you declare `A` and `B` `abstract`, in which case you can't call `new`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just did not implement the method `method` because I tested it on my computer and the following code works:

```
scala> trait T {
 | def method(a:Int) =a
 | }
defined trait T

scala> class A extends T
defined class A

scala> class B extends A
defined class B

scala> val b = new B
b: B = B@164a40a0

scala> b.method(11)
res25: Int = 11
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not compile, because the method is never implemented.  B cannot be instantiated because the classes are all abstract.

Add the method body like this, inside Trait A:

```
def method(a: Int)={
    //do something useful here
}
```

It then compiles, and there are no errors, and indeed, the instance of B may use the method.